# Converting the euclidean distance to manhattan distance

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning

The below calculation is given in spark mlib library to find the euclidean distance

```
private[mllib] def fastSquaredDistance(
      v1: Vector,
      norm1: Double,
      v2: Vector,
      norm2: Double,
      precision: Double = 1e-6): Double = {
    val n = v1.size
    require(v2.size == n)
    require(norm1 >= 0.0 && norm2 >= 0.0)
    val sumSquaredNorm = norm1 * norm1 + norm2 * norm2
    val normDiff = norm1 - norm2
    var sqDist = 0.0

    val precisionBound1 = 2.0 * EPSILON * sumSquaredNorm / (normDiff * normDiff + EPSILON)
    if (precisionBound1 < precision) {
      sqDist = sumSquaredNorm - 2.0 * dot(v1, v2)
    } else if (v1.isInstanceOf[SparseVector] || v2.isInstanceOf[SparseVector]) {
      val dotValue = dot(v1, v2)
      sqDist = math.max(sumSquaredNorm - 2.0 * dotValue, 0.0)
      val precisionBound2 = EPSILON * (sumSquaredNorm + 2.0 * math.abs(dotValue)) /
        (sqDist + EPSILON)
      if (precisionBound2 > precision) {
        sqDist = Vectors.sqdist(v1, v2)
      }
    } else {
      sqDist = Vectors.sqdist(v1, v2)
    }
    sqDist
  }
```

I am very new to machine learning .My question is about how to find manhattan distance by modifying the above code.

Comment: Manhattan-distance is just a subtraction on vectors (with some outer abs). You should not modify the code above! [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any additional context, I'd suggest just implementing the L1 distance in the obvious naive fashion:

```
d_manhatten(u,v) = sum( abs(u[i] - v[i]), i)     // Pseudocode
```

Now, I haven't looked at your code much, but it looks like much of it is (1) concerned about precision (which is less of a problem for L1, compared to L2, since there is no square) and (2) uses the L2 norms as inputs (which, to my knowledge, are not useful in computing the L1 anyway). So modifying the current method may not be so useful.

Also, I hear a lot that premature optimization is the root of all evil, so try the simplest thing first, and if it is unacceptable, then try <s>obfuscating</s> optimizing :)